# formula on lookup column in calculation field of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list and it's columns is like below:

```
    FirstName   LastName   Study    has_Studied

     a            b         civil       yes

     c            f                     no

     h            k          elec       yes
```

study column is a lookup column and source of it's data is in another list.

now i want to make a calculation column like "Has_Studied" column at the top,and it's return value is (yes/no), that shows me "yes" when study column has value and when study column is blank, it shows me "no".

I have tried to make a formula but i got error about lookup column that i do not have access.

it seems easy but i do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adam said, it’s by design that the lookup column can’t be used in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.

The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula:

https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/

Workarounds:
https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1):

I think the lookup column is not supported in calculated fields. To achieve this You can use SharePoint workflow (for SP online You can use MS Flow). The workflow would be started on Item add event or Item updated. After that based on a simple condition You could populate the column.